# str_replace string in a file.txt with another file.txt

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I want to replace some string in searchword.txt file with replaceword.txt file, but with my php code it can only replace the first two strings, i want to replace all the strings in the file.

here is my php code:

```
$txt_s = file_get_contents("searchword.txt");
$txt_s = explode(";", $txt_s);
$txt_r = file_get_contents("replaceword.txt");
$txt_r = explode(";", $txt_r);
$term = str_replace($txt_s, $txt_r, $last_tmp_);
```

here is how my searchword.txt file looks like:

```
hello; modern; corn; banana; apple;
```

here is how my replaceword.txt file looks like:

```
goodbye; fashionable; popcorn; monkey; sweet;
```

how can i replace all the strings, not just first two strings? or may be any different way to do this please let me know.

Comment: i tested your code and it works well on my end.  try `str_ireplace` for insensitive case . see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to strip whitespaces for example with [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$newarray = array_map('trim', $array);
```

Use:

```
$txt_s = file_get_contents("searchword.txt");
$txt_s = array_map( 'trim', explode(";", $txt_s) );
$txt_r = file_get_contents("replaceword.txt");
$txt_r = array_map( 'trim', explode(";", $txt_r) );
$term = str_replace($txt_s, $txt_r, $last_tmp_);
```