# str_replace string with a file.txt

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm sorry I have asked about this before, but with different output. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367022/str-replace-string-in-a-file-txt-with-another-file-txt) is my previous question that already answered. But its inefficient.

I want the searchword and replaceword are in one file. I think this method will be more easier. So i think my code should be like this:

```
$txt_search = file_get_contents("replaced.txt");
$txt_search = array_map( 'trim', explode("=", $txt_s) );
$txt_replace = file_get_contents("replaced.txt");
$txt_replace = array_map( 'trim', explode(";", $txt_r) );
$term = str_replace($txt_s, $txt_r, $last_tmp_);
```

And inside the replaced.txt file should be like this:

```
hello=hi; modern=fashionable; apple=banana;
```

So for the result i want 'hello' replaced by 'hi'. What should I change from my code? or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a map of replacements

```
$arr = parse_ini_string(str_replace(";", "\n", file_get_contents("replaced.txt")));
```

if you have control over the contents of the replaced.txt file just change the ;'s over to newlines and and use parse_ini_file("replaced.txt"); to get the same array, this might be a little saner to maintain.

then you can do the replacements with

```
$term = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $last_tmp_);
```